# sorting in javascript on page-load

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/fjamal21/pen/LYYwGQZ) as shown below in which I want to sort alphabetically eveyrthing in JavaScript. 
The snippets of code in the codepen which I have used:

```
 <div id="vods-house-senate-committee">
        <div class="column-1">
            <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Affairs </a></p>
            <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Agriculture</a></p>
            <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Canadian</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-2">
            <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Indigenous</a></p>
            <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Industry</a></p>
            <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Justice</a></p>
        </div>
 </div>

    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("vods-house-senate-committee");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
     }
    }
```

**Problem Statement:**  I am wondering what **JS** I need to add so that it sorts everything alphabetically on page-load.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort everything alphabetically" ?  They're already in alphabetical order...

Comment: @devlincarnate No, its no. **Access** is coming after **Affairs**.

Comment: Access? I don't see it...

Comment: @flash - I don't see "Access" in the HTML you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort the texts in the two columns (and not "everything"... which is quite a lot), you could first collect all these texts, then sort them with the standard `sort` method, and then repopulate the columns:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#vods-house-senate-committee p"));
    elems.sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent));
    let columns = document.querySelectorAll("#vods-house-senate-committee > div");
    let len = Math.ceil(elems.length / columns.length);
    for (let column of columns) {
        for (let i = 0; i < len && elems.length; i++) column.append(elems.shift());
    }
});
```

```css
#vods-house-senate-committee { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }
a { margin: 5px }
```

```html
<div id="vods-house-senate-committee">
    <div class="column-1">
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Industry</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Agriculture</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Justice</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Indigenous</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Canadian</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Affairs </a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```